# SQL server - Create a view to validate a column against 3 tables and get maximum record for an RECID

Tags: sql, view, compare

I have three tables all containing RECID(unique) and DATE field. Table D1 which contain records of history, D1c which may/may not contain same records,DELETE LOG table which may/may not contain same RECID which is deleted from D1 table .And i am trying to create a view which has to meet the following conditions. Is it possible to create this in a single view??

1. Compare the RECID between D1 and D1c
2. If same RECID in both tables , get record with max(date)
3. IF RECID in D1 and not in D1c - get record FROM D1
4. IF RECID in D1c and not in D1 then check if DATE(D1c) >  DATE(DLOG) ,if this case is true then INSERT INTO D1 SELECT * FROM D1c
5. IF RECID in D1c and not in D1 then  check if DATE(D1c) <  DATE(DLOG) if this case is true then dont show in the VIEW.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have tried the below code . Please validate it meets all the above said conditions. Or let me know whats the other efficient way to do it.

Comment: WITH MATCH AS(SELECT RECID,CREATION_TIME_RR FROM D1 UNION SELECT RECID,CREATION_TIME_RR FROM D1C
),MISMATCH1 AS (SELECT RECID,CREATION_TIME_RR FROM D1
EXCEPT SELECT RECID,CREATION_TIME_RR FROM D1C
) ,MISMATCH2 AS (SELECT C.RECID,C.CREATION_TIME_RR 
FROM D1C C JOIN DLOG DLOG ON C.RECID = DLOG.RECID AND C.CREATION_TIME_RR > DLOG.CREATION_TIME_RR
EXCEPT
SELECT S.RECID,S.CREATION_TIME_RR FROM D1 S 
)

Comment: SELECT T1.*
FROM D1 T1 
JOIN ( SELECT RECID,MAX(CREATION_TIME_RR)CREATION_TIME_RR
  FROM MATCH  GROUP BY RECID)MAXI
ON MAXI.RECID=T1.RECID AND MAXI.CREATION_TIME_RR=T1.CREATION_TIME_RR
LEFT JOIN MISMATCH1 M1 ON T1.RECID=M1.RECID

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code.